# Posting data using 'header(location: )' in php

Tags: php, header, http-post

i've just made a sign script for my website. The form posts the data to itself and then checks to see if all the data is correct. if so it then loads a payment page. To load this payment page i use:

```
  header(location: payment.php);
```

So i want to send data over to the page that im loading, i though i could use:

```
  $userid = mysql_insert_id();
```

to get the last id added to the database but its not working, maybe im using it wrong though. Anyway, i know what in my database the email address on every record with be unique as well as the id, so i thought maybe i'd change the header to:

```
 header(location: payment.php?email=$email);
```

This way it would put the email address into the URL and i'd be able to find the user again on the next page by using:

```
 $email = $_GET['email'];
```

Now this works fine and from that i can get the users details from the database. However i thought that putting someones email address into the URL wasn't best practice but i can't for the life of me think of another way around it.

Any suggestions or good ways of doing this?

Thanks for the time.

Comment: What's about using a session and store data into the session?

Comment: As soon as i see those words, it hits me! Thanks.

Comment: As an aside, the `Location:` header [should be fully-qualified](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30) (and not use relative locations).

Comment: To be honest, despite all the complex session stuff posted, there is  nothing really wrong in posting the email address as you first thought when you think about it. However, if you are going to running a query using this, you will need to sanitize the input as is needed or anything received in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should go back and check why `mysql_insert_id()` isn't working. That'll be the best way to get the data across.

Comment: I thought i t was because i am using that function of a different page from the original form.... Does that matter?

Comment: Is the `mysql_query()` where you insert the user in the same page? As long as it is, `mysql_insert_id()` should work fine.

Comment: Nope, i guess that's what i wasn't getting..... So maybe i should just get the id and then send it over. Thanks.

Comment: Yes you should do that. Always best to do that.

Answer (score 3):

### Use persistent data to be associated with client

Use `$_SESSION` to associate data with the current client, don't forget to call `session_start ();` before you actually append data to the array.

*Note: This will require the use of cookies in the client*

---

### Include functionality into one file

Though if the only purpose of the page where the data is posted is to validate data, do that and then you could `include ("payment.php");`, no redirects required.

Or put the functionality of the form-landing page in `payment.php` instead.

---

### Use a GET-parameter sent to payment.php

You could also redirect to `payment.php?id=<val>` where `<val>` is the id of the transaction, though you should not expose the real id since this will decrease security.

Unless you check to see so that a user can only access `id`s who actually belongs to them.

A hash of the payment info can be used instead since this value will not easily, or at all, be guessed.

Answer (score 1):

Just start a session before doing anything in the two pages.

```
<?php session_start()
```

and on the verification page do something like

```
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
```

and finally on the payment page you can get the email then via

```
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
```

Comment: Are there any security implications that should be looked at when using SESSION?

Comment: well if you are using a cdn (so no common php host) you need to save the data somewhere else (e.g. use memcache). also the user needs to have cookies enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Once you update your payment, create/ get your GUID or your unique id from your DB, and redirect to your success page with your guid or unique id, exposing this id will not harm anyway.